# Post to Sharepoint List using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, post, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I'm fairly new to programming in Objective C. I am trying to post an item to a Sharepoint list. The way that I have to post to this is to overlay another object in the list, but also to create a new object right after that. I'm a bit confused on what to do and have already made a connection to the list to receive data from it, but do not know how to post to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint's List Web Service has the methods that allows you to create new items. Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx) reference.

Comment: Thank you, that helped quiet a bit, but I don't know how to translate that code to Objective C. I am trying to post the Sharepoint List from an iPad app.

Comment: I haven't worked with Objective C or it's API's but I would assume the Web Service call should be fairly standard. A typical SOAP request and SOAP response.